# Application design distorts

Tags: iphone, ios

In my Iphone application, when application running stage in  between skype call comes, the call details will show in status bar and status bar height automatically increase and my application design distorts

How can i solve this issue?

if skype call is not happening everything is perfect..

Comment: is ur screen within a scroll view?

Comment: Uninstall skype..!!!! :D

Comment: Yes..but same happened in scroll view